# Javascript MVVM design patterns - how to track dirty state and who should do Ajaxing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, design-patterns, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm part way through a pretty complex Knockout.js app using the mapping plugin to work with a deep object graph which closely mirrors server side domain objects. I've been refining my patterns as I go to something which works pretty well for my own slightly awkward context but I'd like to know if it's a good / bad overall way to approach MVVM Javascript.

Essentially my page pattern is to have a revealing module function which acts a bit like a controller - it owns the hierarchy of view models and is responsible for detecting changes, Ajaxing changes to the server and using the mapping plugin to update its view model graph with any flow-on changes which may come back in the response as JSON. I've done it this way because my domain is such that a small change in one part of the graph, when validated on the server, may result in changes / removals in distant parts of the graph. When this happens I need a common point at which to re-map the changes, present message dialogs to the user, etc.

All of my view models are instantiable functions and I've designed it so that they know nothing about the page they're used in, or the server (i.e. they don't do their own Ajaxing). The constructor of each view model creates its children via mapping options and each level is passed a reference to its parent. I've implemented a generic dirty flag which most of the view models use, and when a change occurs they pass a reference to themselves up the chain to a "dirty view model" observable at the top, which the module is subscribed to. I know this sounds a bit odd but it seemed the best way to approach it because items at each level are constantly being added and removed so I can't statically subscribe to properties at initialization time. And I don't want to keep removing and re-adding subscriptions each time I re-map my graph (which can get quite big).

From a pure efficiency point of view this isn't the best. The simplest way would be that each view model directly calls a function in the module when it needs to, but that type of coupling has to be wrong. Or I could pass in a reference to the module (or its relevant function) to each view model constructor, and the view model calls that, a bit like Javascript dependency injection. But that just seems too abstract. This is complex enough as it is.

Should I be looking at a higher level framework such as Backbone to sit on top of all this? Is injecting the module reference really too abstract? Or does this way of structuring things basically make sense as it is? I'm keen to hear from anyone who has worked on similarly challenging scenarios as to how you progressed and refined your patterns.

EDIT: I should have clarified that for various reasons, this app works in "save as you go" mode, whereby a change at a given level causes an immediate discrete Ajax post of just that one view model (not including its children) to be sent to the server (which may return a result which represents a change to just about anything else). Despite this annoying need for constant Ajaxing as opposed to pure client side action, Knockout.js has still made my app WAY more elegant, maintainable and scalable than my MVC apps of Olde.

Comment: Have you considered using pub/sub instead of parental references? http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

Comment: That seems really cool, I've just downloaded the Niemaster's ko.postbox project and am experimenting with that to see if it can fit my purposes. I suspect I will still need my generic DirtyFlag object for its view model state comparison logic, but the pub/sub could probably simplify the communication with the module a lot. Cheers, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Niemeyer has you covered there to: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Yep, I used that as the starting point for my dirty flag. I'm not using toJSON for doing comparison though, because at each level of my view model hierarchy I'm only concerned with changes to properties at the root level, not children (plus, doing toJSON all the time with big structures would get pretty inefficient). My dirty flag constructor also optionally accepts an array of property names to ignore.

Comment: I've refactored my dirty view model management to use publish and subscribe for communicating with the page module, which has simplified my code quite a bit and seemingly made it run a bit quicker too. I don't think there's a "correct" answer to my question, I basically wanted a heads-up that my design isn't completely ridiculous, but this was a good suggestion so stick that into an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Decoupling your viewmodels and reducing references can be achieved with a pub/sub model, like the one Ryan Niemeyer [discusses here](http://knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html).

Ryan also made a Dirty flag for viewmodels, which can be [found here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html).